# Wordpress Page ID within Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode

I am using a plugin called: InPost Gallery. I have added the shortcode to a template file but the shortcode needs the post ID to find the images related to the page. Is it possible to get the post id added to a shortcode in a template file?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[inpost_nivo slide_width='600px' slide_height='auto' thumb_width='75' thumb_height='75' post_id="28" skin='light' transition_effect='random' transition_speed='600' autoslide='5000' control_nav='1' control_nav_thumbs='1' direction_nav='1' direction_nav_hide='0' controlNavThumbs='0' random_start='0' pause_on_hover='1' show_description='1' box_rows='4' box_cols='8' slices='15' start_slide='0' id='' random='0' group='0' show_in_popup='0' album_cover='' album_cover_width='200' album_cover_height='200' popup_width='800' popup_max_height='600' popup_title='Gallery' type='nivo'][/inpost_nivo]"); ?>
```

You can see the post_id is set to 28. This needs to change depending on the page currently being viewed.

If this is possible it would be a great help to hear your suggestions.

Many thanks

Comment: If you aren't using the shortcode inside of "The Loop", then have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's within the *loop*, you can for example use:

```
<?php 

// Display shortcode for current post:

$s = sprintf( '[inpost_nivo post_id="%d"]', get_the_ID() );

echo do_shortcode( $s ); 

?>
```

You could also try to skip the `post_id` attribute, and see if it has the same default setup.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help! its working now, I just had to change the echo do_shotcode to  sc :)